# Does nativescript support windows 10

Tags: nativescript

Does nativescript support windows 10?
I did not find windows support in nativescript official site: https://docs.nativescript.org/

Comment: [Quote from your link](https://docs.nativescript.org/) "*With the NativeScript CLI you can develop, build, and debug your apps locally on macOS, **Windows**, and Linux*"

Comment: Thanks, I was asking whether nativescript can develop windows app. Not develop android or ios app on a windows machine.

Comment: {N} only support iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t create windows apps with Nativescript. But if you are interested in creating desktop applications with JavaScript/Typescript or Angular, take a look at [ElectronJS](https://www.electronjs.org).